# My media query doesn't work on my android device

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

My media query works fine in pc's browser when i re-size it, but when i access my website through localhost with my android device, my media query doesn't work? What can the problem be? My device has 480 x 800 pixels resolutions.

Here is my media query:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
#main{width:90%;position:relative;}
div.itemRelated ul li {float: left;width: 20%;}
div.itemRelated ul li a img{width:90%;}
div.itemRelated ul li a{text-align:center;}
.maincontent{width:90%;font-size:.7em;}
#base{width:100%;}
h2, h2 a:link, h2 a:visited{font-size:.7em;}
#container_header{width:96%;}
#container_slideshow{display:none;}
#container_main{width:90%;margin: 0 auto;}
.wrapper960{margin:0 auto;}/*ova treba da se cepne*/
#sidecol_b, #sidecol_a{display:none;}
#content_remainder{width:96%;clear:both;top:0;}
#container_bottom_modules{display:none;}
#container_spacer3{display:none;}
#jazik{float:left;}
.sigProContainer sigProClassic sigProClassic{margin-left:10%;}
#hornav{padding-left:5px;}
#hornav ul li a{font-size:1em;padding: 0 5px;width:8%}
#container_header{width:100%;}
#socialmedia{display:none;}
#search {clear:both;top: 20%;left: 15%;}
.content{width:66%;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are specifically targeting android device, or any device with `480x800` try this

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
  /* Style goes here */
}
```

A pretty good [**article**](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) if you like to read

Answer (score 12):

The width of Android devices is often not the actual screensize. If you want to have the width of the screen you need a viewport meta tag.

```
 <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Use this meta tag in your HTML

**Update:**

The code above also disables the scaling (zooming), which is not nice for users. So you can do it without disabling scaling to:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content ="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: +1 for the right answer. However, preventing the user from scaling may not be desirable. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` is sufficient.

Comment: @primo You are right! Disabling scaling is not the best usage.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across a similar issue surrounding the multitude of Android devices screen widths and screen densities.

In the end I settled on this media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 765px) {
    /* Style goes here */
}
```

But [here](http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/) is a handy site that provides more device and orientation specific media queries